# what does data frame equals a pattern means

Tags: r

I have the following data frame

```
X
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  1  0  1  0  1
2  1  1  0  0  0
3  1  1  0  0  1
4  0  0  1  1  0
5  1  0  0  0  0
6  1  2  3  0  0
```

And a vector

```
pattern
[1] 0 1 0
```

What does X == pattern means? I cannot interpret the following output.

```
> X == pattern
     X1    X2    X3    X4    X5
1 FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
2  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
3 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
4  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
5  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
6 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: Please use `dput(yourDataframe)` to show your data or a definition of the dataframe-

Comment: I belive relevant parts in "_An Introduction to R_" would be [2.2 Vector arithmetic](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Vectors-and-assignment) and [5.4.1 The recycling rule](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#The-recycling-rule).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what is happening, is the values in X are being compared to pattern row by row starting with pattern[1].

```
X[1,] is compared to pattern[1],
Then X[2,] is compared to pattern[2]
Then X[3,] is compared to pattern[3]
Then X[4,] is compared to pattern[1]
Then X[5,] is compared to pattern[2]... and so on.
```

Creating comparisons as shown below

```
   X1    X2    X3    X4    X5
1  1==0  0==0  1==0  0==0  1==0   #pattern = 0
2  1==1  1==1  0==1  0==1  0==1   #pattern = 1
3  1==0  1==0  0==0  0==0  1==0   #pattern = 0
4  0==0  0==0  1==0  1==0  0==0   #pattern = 0
5  1==1  0==1  0==1  0==1  0==1   #pattern = 1
6  1==0  2==0  3==0  0==0  0==0   #pattern = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The pattern  0, 1, 0 is smaller than the size of the data frame,  so it will be replicated enough times so that all of the necessary comparisons can be made so it is the same as making the matrix

```
(M = matrix(c(0,1,0), nrow=6, ncol=5))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    1    1    1    1    1
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0
[5,]    1    1    1    1    1
[6,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

and saying `X == M`

Answer (score 0):

You can understand the operation as: It transformed the `matrix`/`data.frame` into `vector` (by columns) and use it to compare with the pattern. Then put the result back (by columns) to `matrix`/`data.frame`.

```
# X == pattern is equal to:
matrix(c(as.matrix(X)) == pattern, ncol=ncol(X))

#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
# [1,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# [2,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# [4,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [5,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

You can do some experiments like:

```
Y <- X[-6, ]
Y

#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
# 1  1  0  1  0  1
# 2  1  1  0  0  0
# 3  1  1  0  0  1
# 4  0  0  1  1  0
# 5  1  0  0  0  0

Y == pattern

#      X1    X2   X3    X4    X5
# 1 FALSE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# 2  TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# 3 FALSE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# 4  TRUE  TRUE TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# 5  TRUE  TRUE TRUE FALSE  TRUE    

matrix(c(as.matrix(Y)) == pattern, ncol=ncol(Y))

#       [,1]  [,2] [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
# [1,] FALSE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# [2,]  TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# [3,] FALSE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# [4,]  TRUE  TRUE TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# [5,]  TRUE  TRUE TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

#### Data

```
X <- structure(list(X1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), X2 = c(0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 2L), X3 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L), X4 = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), X5 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("X1", 
"X2", "X3", "X4", "X5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```